# What's the procedure of upload a java spring based web application to the real server, and how to use load balance to the server?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, server, web-development-server

I am creating a simple web project with mysql database using Java Spring-MVC. Now I want to understand the full workflow of the web system development cycle.

- How to upload a project to a real server?.
- How to sync the database to a real server?.
- How DC and DRC is sync with each other?.
- Why and how to use "Load balancer" to the server?.

Apologize, if I said something non-technical.

Comment: Well, I don't think we have to upload database to the real server. By the by, what are you referring ''real server" here?

Comment: what does DC and DRC refer to?

Comment: Data center & Data Recovery Center.

Comment: Other Approach for question 1 : Why you don't use a continuous integration ( Exp : Jenkins & Nexus) to build, tag, and deploy a version. & a script to install your *war file* in your server.

Answer (score 1):

I'll not go into too much details but here is the gist of it.

Before anything, the first thing to get sorted is the operating system of the server be it Linux, Windows Server and so on. The choice of operating system will depend on the constraints and requirements.

**How to upload a project to a real server?**

Any files which needs to be served should be hosted and served by a web application server such as [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [IIS](https://www.iis.net/), [Websphere](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/websphere-application-platform) and many more.

The choice of web application server depends on a few things, such as the server operating system, the web application implementation and so on. For your case, which is a Spring MVC implemented in Java, you'll need to use a web application server that supports that, such as Apache Tomcat for example.

Once the choice is made, install the web application server on the server. After that, install your web application on the web application server.

**How to sync the database to a real server?**

I infer that you're referring about the connectivity between the Java web application to the database? Do comment if its not.

The Spring MVC web application can connect directly to the database via JDBC or JNDI (provided that the necessary configuration is configured on the web application server).

Of course, the database can be connected locally (if installed on the same server) or remotely.

**How `DC` and `DRC` is sync with each other?**

This is too broad to cover and the recovery strategy differs for every Data Center providers. But broadly, they employ redundancy and replication strategy to ensure the data is always backed up and available. Check with the providers individually for a better picture.

**Why and how to use "Load balancer" to the server?**

The load balancer primary purpose is to distribute the work load across multiple servers to achieve better [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte). To do so, it sits in front of the servers and routes the request accordingly. Some of the load balancing solutions such as [f5](https://f5.com/resources/white-papers/load-balancing-101-nuts-and-bolts-31392) explains about load balancing in greater detail.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install Application Server on your machine.

Step 2: Install JDK, Database server which are dependent on your application.

Step 3: Export your war from Eclipse/Netbeans

Step 4: Paste your war file on app server's deployment folder (webapps incase of tomcat)

Step 5: your application deployed